# Building Python on Unix

Tags: python, makefile

This is a question regarding building python and its modules on any type of unix-based OS. 
When I build python, by default it looks for libraries in /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib etc. 
If I want to change the library search path and add my own directory to be searched for before the default paths, how do I do this? 
I read that I need to modify `setup.py` file. Is the lib_dirs to be modified? Like this

```
lib_dirs = self.compiler.library_dirs + ['/lib64', '/usr/lib64','/lib','/usr/lib']
```

But modifying this  did not help. Is there any other way to this? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to search your own directories first, they should probably go at the beginning, not the end...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build 32bit python 2.6 on 64bit Linux ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867131/how-to-build-32bit-python-2-6-on-64bit-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable. It's used by the Python interpreter to figure out where to look for libraries/modules to import.

> > export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/whatever/other/path/you/want