# Create 32-bit exe's from python code on 64-bit machine

Tags: python

I have already created a 64-bit program for windows using cx freeze on a 64-bit machine. I am using Windows 7 64-bit Home premium. py2exe is not working because as i understand it does not work with python 3.2.2 yet. Is there an option i have to specify in cx freeze to compile in 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install 32 bit Python?

Comment: No, Should I uninstall my other installation first?

Comment: I will also install the 32-bit of cx freeze. Correct?

Comment: Doubt you need to uninstall anything. Expect you need 32 bit versions of both Python and cx freeze, not that I know anything of latter.

Comment: Could I just install them in different directories?

Comment: That's the normal approach. I have loads of different pythons in different folders.

Comment: By the way, how to create 64-bit exe's from python code on 32-bit machine, if ever possible?

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352783/43390

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/454254/173666

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/905083/173666

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To produce 32 bit executables you need to install 32-bit versions of Python and cx_freeze.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201282/1959808

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers already given:

1. To compile/freeze python code for different architectures (x86/x64), **install** both, **x86 and x64 versions of python**, to your system and corresponding variations of **all required modules and libraries** to your python installations so both installations have the same (required) set of packages installed.
2. The next step is to check that your global **OS environment** is **configuredcorrectly**. The following Windows environment variables need to point to the appropriate installation of Python you want to freeze to, You should know which locations they need to point to:

   - **%PATH%**
   - **%PYTHONHOME%**
   - **%PYTHONPATH%**
3. Once you've set them up properly, **re-open any terminals to make sure you've got the new environment loaded** (re-login to your Windows session if necessary to properly refresh your environment) and you are ready to **run your cx_freeze** and any other python-related build ops to get your final builds for that architecture.
4. Once done with those builds, re-run the process from step 2. to change your Windows environment to the next python installation and build.

To speed up the environment-change process I either script those steps or use a VM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All the "produce an executable from Python code" methods I know of basically create a file that bundles up the Python interpreter with the Python code you want to execute inside a single file. It is nothing at all like compiling C code to an executable; Python is just about impossible to compile to machine code in any significantly more useful way than just gluing the Python bytecode to the machine code for a Python interpreter.

So that's almost certainly why you can't produce a 32 bit exe from a 64 bit installation of Python; there isn't a 32 bit interpreter to embed in the output file.