# Is is possible to compile a 32-bit python program with Nuitka?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, nuitka

I have tried this command:

`py -m nuitka --mingw64 --standalone --onefile --windows-disable-console --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico program_name.py`

It only generates 64-bit programs even by removing the `--mingw64` parameter. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create 32-bit exe's from python code on 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988772/create-32-bit-exes-from-python-code-on-64-bit-machine)

Answer (score 0):

My Development Environment is

- Windows 10 (32bit)
- cl compiler (32bit)

python -m nuitka --windows-disable-console --standalone --windows-uac-admin --low-memory YOUR_PROGRAM.py

It works well.