# Compiling 32-bit python on a 64 bit machine

Tags: python-2.7, 32bit-64bit, spss

While I know this has been asked here before, it has been several years since the last time I can find, and there was no successful solution to this question, so here we go.

I have a copy of x64-bit SPSS for *nix that requires on a 32-bit python2.7.3 installation for extended functionality. Unfortunately for me, I run an ubuntu x64 machine, and I've been unable to compile 32bit python on it. I've been able follow both sets of instructions also tested at this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/29253/how-can-i-install-a-32bit-python-on-64-bit-ubuntu but have not had any success with it following the flags. Both resulted in the correct location/unicode settings, but compiled x64 versions. I've checked for missing packages, but none of the recommended packages seem to be missing.

Any help with compiling python (or even an alternative method) would be greatly appreciated. As it is, the only solution I can think of is to create a chroot jail.

Comment: I would definitely go for a chroot, with schroot. Maintenance will be easier, and no compilation. BTW, I think the question would be better in askubuntu.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201282/1959808

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running 64-bit SPSS and using 64-bit Python?

Comment: I am actually running 64-bit spss. What I'm aiming for is enabling the python plugin essentials, which IBM's helpdesk informed me was only compatible with 32-bit python